# Adding animation to content property, after hovering

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions, font-awesome

What I am trying to achieve is an animation when you hover an element like this:

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
.home:hover::after{
  content: " Home";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
```

So when you hover the `a`, some additional text will be display, but I couldn't find any transition for smooth showing it. Don't mind answering to use `transition: all ...`, because this isn't working. Live example of the website can be found at http://www.testingc.ga or in the snippet below.

**iframe snippet** (Open the navigation to see the elements with the `content: "Text"` on hover.

```css
iframe{
  border: none;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.tc.gamingprouk.net">Error</iframe>
```

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: you added javascript and jquery on your tag but you want it pure CSS, update your post

Comment: What are you trying to acheive exactly? The example you provided is not helping (couldn't see the TEXT).

Comment: @ibrahim check the updated snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
I made a fade-in / fade-out effect with a CSS transition

```css
.home {
  position: relative;
}
.home::after {
  content: 'Home';
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.home:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<a href="#" class="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
```

Comment: In this case the text **Home** is displayed, but with <code>opacity: 0</code> untill you hover it. I am adding this to a bootstrap navigation, and it doesn't looks good if the text is still there, but not shown. Live example of the navigation: http://testingc.ga

Comment: What effect do you want? changing width to / from zero can also be done easily

Comment: Any kind of animation, but the text must not be shown on the page before the user hovers an element, because it takes space in the navigation even if it is with <code>opacity: 0</code> or <code>color: transparent</code>. It works with <code>display: none</code>, but there is no transition for the <code>display</code> property name.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the original state first then animate it on hover

```
a:after {
    content: 'Home';
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity: 0.5s linear;
}

a:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: In this case the text **Home** is displayed, but with <code>opacity: 0</code> untill you hover it. I am adding this to a bootstrap navigation, and it doesn't looks good if the text is still there, but not shown. Live example of the navigation: http://testingc.ga

Comment: Animate the width too in that case

Comment: I have * {transition: all .5s linear;} in global.css, so width is animated alredy

Comment: Have you set width:0; and then width: 100px on hover for example. Animating from auto to a numeric value wont work. Here is an example on the menu of this site [link](http://themedemoignition.dweb.vcarsdna.com/vehicle/)

Comment: in the website you've shared, they use a **<span>** not **content**. I have tried animating the width, but it doesn't works.

Comment: Here is an example, note you need to specify the transition on both the element and the element:after. [jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/becuxoqipi/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: thank you! You can post it as an answer with a snippet ;)